# Little error APIMAN in installation guide

Tags: apiman

> 4.6.1.1. Create a Custom Enterprise Plugin Registry JSON
>
> The first thing you will need to do is express all of your enterprise
>   plugins as a JSON file. The format of the JSON file is specific to
>   apiman. You can find an example of the format here:
>
> https://github.com/apiman/apiman-api-catalog/blob/master/catalog.json

I think that the good link is

https://github.com/apiman/apiman-plugin-registry/blob/master/registry.json

And I don't know the process to contact apiman team.

Comment: Why not make a PR? https://github.com/apiman/apiman-guides/blob/master/installation-guide/en-US/Guide.asciidoc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And I don't know the process to contact apiman team.

All of the following are from the *Get Involved* tab on the [apiman website](http://www.apiman.io):

- Issue/Bug tracker: https://issues.jboss.org/projects/APIMAN
- Mailing List: https://lists.jboss.org/mailman/listinfo/apiman-user
- IRC: http://www.apiman.io/latest/chat.html
- Make a PR: https://www.github.com/apiman ([apiman-guides](https://www.github.com/apiman/apiman-guides/) is the one you're looking for)